# Coin flip gamble

Tags: probability, gambling

You have an amount of money to bet on a fair coin flipping and landing on heads. How much should you bet as a function of your balance to maximize your probability of profiting if you play $x$ times?

Comment: Try this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

Comment: @sas That is a fascinating and useful case, but he is talking about a much simpler, non compounding gambling situation, you may just be complicating things more than necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the previous answers didn't fully appreciate the question, which I think has multiple interpretations.

Let $A$ be your initial amount of money, and $x$ be the number of times you need to bet. Now there are two ambiguities:

1. Do you have to bet *exactly* $x$ times (i.e., you cannot bet all of your money until the final bet)?
2. Do you have to bet the same amount each time?

Suppose (1) and (2) are both true. If $x$ is odd you have exactly a 50% chance of profiting, no matter what. However, if $x$ is even you have strictly *less* than a 50% chance of profiting. For example, if $x = 2$, then you have only a 25% chance of profiting.

Suppose (1) is false and (2) is true. Then clearly, you will simply bet some odd number of times $t \leq x$, and have a 50% chance of profiting.

Suppose (2) is false (regardless of (1)). Then you can actually achieve a $1 - .5^x$ chance of profiting. For each round $i$ until you win a coin toss, simply bet $A * .5^{x-i+1}$ dollars. $\sum_{i=1}^\infty A*.5^i = A$, so clearly 
you will never go broke, because $x$ is finite. However, each bet is more than the sum of all previous bets. Thus, once you win one coin toss, you will have more than $A$ dollars, and can simply bet a small enough sliver of your profits for the remaining bets to guarantee that you profit.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a truly fair coin, with a 50% chance of each side coming up, the chance of winning and the chances of losing are equal, and losing $X$ dollars or gaining $X$ dollars cancel out to an average profit of $0$ dollars absolutely regardless of how much you bet.

Comment: If you bet half your balance and win then lose, you won't be back where you started.

Comment: no, im saying that each individual bet has an average payout of zero. If i bet 1 dollar, then i have 50% chance of winning 1 dollar and 50% chance of losing 1 dollar. Adding these together we get $0.5*1+0.5*-1=0$ So for that bet, the average value is zero.

Comment: But we're not betting a set amount of money, we're betting a set fraction of what we have at each coin toss. The expected value is still whatever we started with, though.

Comment: ok, then replace 1 in the previous equation with x, x being the amount you are betting. No matter how much you bet, the expected value of each bet is zero, there is no profitable way to bet. How you bet doesnt change the mean of the result, but it does affect the standard deviation of the result

Comment: for more read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin